# Stateless bean does not expose default method of interface implemented

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi, ejb-3.1

I have a default method defined on an interface (`AsynchronousTarget`) and then implement that interface by `@Stateless` bean. Here is the interface and the bean:

```
public interface AsynchronousTarget {    
   default void invoke(String id) {
          ...
   }
}

@Stateless
@Local(value = { ApplicationTransfer.class, AsynchronousTarget.class})
public class ApplicationTransfer implements AsynchronousTarget {
}
```

I expected my bean to have this method exposed but when I inject the bean using CDI's `@Inject` via interface and try to call a method it throws the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0067: Method does not exist public abstract void AsynchronousTarget.invoke(java.lang.String)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponentInstance.getInterceptor(BasicComponentInstance.java:102)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:185)
... 267 more
```

Comment: if you expect people to help you, you should provide the maximum amount of information.. please edit and add the interface and implementing class code

Comment: @Repoker Ok, so I added my code but I don't think it adds value.

Comment: And I don't think ejb3.0 knew about default methods... at all. And why is it both 3.0 and 3.1 related. If you use 3.1 why worry about 3.0?  And this is an EJB, not CDI, so why also tag it CDI?
And code always adds value if posted correctly. For al we know you made a typo somewhere.

Comment: Since default method implementation in interfaces is available since version 8 I understand you are using java 8 or above (for compilation), The server may be running a different version though, have you checked your wildfly server and java version? @Mike the source always adds value! :)

Comment: Yes, I am using WF 14.0.1.Final, java version is 8.

Comment: @Kukeltje I added CDI tag because I am injecting ApplicationTransfer using '@Inject'. Don't know if it has some impact on how interceptors are built. How could I make typo if I built and deployed my application?